# Don't know how to access a #document in the DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to access a #document in the DOM with Javascript but i don't know how to,it is in the image below.

[#document example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hC4mj.png)

It's like Body>div class>div.horizontal container>div.main centre>div#ph-main-centre.placeholder>div-optiframeappincludecomponent>iframe#virtualsAppMain.iframecontainer>html>body.ng-scope.the html is what i'm trying to access.
    `var ifframe = document.getElementbyid(iframe);`
    `iframe.contentDocument`
/*/returns null/*/
    `iframe.contentWindow`
//returns restricted//
how do i access the contents of the iframe?

Comment: This question needs work to be answerable. [Please follow this guide to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: all codes on there returns undefined.

Comment: The #document is not a placeholder its a document.

Answer (score 0):

If you find the frame containing the `#document`, you can access the contents as `frame.contentDocument`.

Comment: iframe.contentDocument returns null.

Comment: You can only access contentDocument if the cross-origin headers are set properly and it is the same domain.

Comment: contentDocument returns null but contentWindow returns restricted.

Comment: `var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhr.responseType = "document";
     xhr.withCredentials = "true";
    xhr.method = "GET";
   xhr.origin = "example.com";
      xhronreadystatechange = function() {if(xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200)console.log(xhr.responseText)};
       xhr.open('GET','example.com','True');
          xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','example.com');
      xhr.send();`

Comment: i'm lost.@Strikeskids.

Comment: you want to access an iframe, which content is loaded via different server or you are just not allowed to access it. Search for CORS https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS and also check services like this http://anyorigin.com/

Comment: Thanks @mario,i'm on it.

Answer (score 0):

what do you want to achive after you access it? Can you provide an example code?

to access a DOM element by class in JS use it like this.

```
var coolElement = document.getElementsByClassName("coolelementclassname")
```

Please also refer to MDN. [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className)

Comment: i want to access it's children up to another element. `var ifframe = document.getElementById('iframe'); ifframe.contentwindow/contentdocument; var iframedoc = ifframe.contentWindow/document; ifframedoc.body; ifframedoc.body.childelement[1]; up to the element i am looking for. @Mario